# mqtt.Client(streamBuilder, options) example with mqtt in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket, mqtt

Can anyone give an example of how this function `mqtt.Client(streamBuilder, options)` is used?
https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/#mqttclientstreambuilder-options

I would appreciate it if you showed it in detail.

Comment: What have you tried? Given what the function does without knowing more about where you want to use it we can't really say. Also just asking for an example is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: i am trying to get data from mqtt broker via mqtt over websocket protocol and i don't know how to write what the streamBuilder function looks like

Comment: There is no need for that function to use MQTT over Websockets, just pass a `ws://` URL to the connect function.

Comment: Thank you very much but I still want to know how that function is used because I wanted to dig deeper into it

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code for the mqtt.js library it's self, it uses this internally for it's own WebSocket implementation.

[lib/connect/ws.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/lib/connect/ws.js) build a WebSocket connection and returns the NodeJS Stream object that represents the open socket to the broker to the MQTTClient() constructor.

In fact the all the files (except `index.js`) in the lib/connect directory are examples of the streamBuilder that need to be passed into that constructor.